# Getting the Timeout Error While Try to open chrome through Robotframework keyword = Open Chrome Browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, rpa, robotframework-browser

I am passing this keyword in robot file

```
 Open Chrome Browser    ${URL}    maximized=true
```

Getting the below error:

> Chrome: Timeout value connect was <object object at
> 0x00000197DC5C7D10>, but it must be an int, float or None.

Comment: Can you add more information? Your keyword "Open Chrome Browser" looks like a custom one that contains "Open Browser" or a similar keyword. Check what parameters are passed there and add them to this question.

Comment: I get something similar, is it a bug on new library?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me after building a new Docker image with updated Python libraries. The issue seems to be related to the version of `urllib`. When I backed out the newly-built image and replaced it with one that had a version of `urllib` that was < 2.0 this problem disappeared.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180798/jenkins-job-failing-for-urllib3-valueerror-timeout-value-connect-was-object-o) has more information.

Comment: This bug report was helpful for me: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6432#issuecomment-1537903264