# Jenkins Job Failing for urllib3: ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x7efe5adb9aa0>, but it must be an int, float or None

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests, jenkins-pipeline, urllib3

As of May 4, 2023, at 16:00, I started seeing one of our Jenkins job failing with the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 822, in get_info
     return json.loads(self.jenkins_open(
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 560, in jenkins_open
     return self.jenkins_request(req, add_crumb, resolve_auth).text
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 576, in jenkins_request
     self.maybe_add_crumb(req)
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 373, in maybe_add_crumb
     response = self.jenkins_open(requests.Request(
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 560, in jenkins_open
     return self.jenkins_request(req, add_crumb, resolve_auth).text
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 579, in jenkins_request
     self._request(req))
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 553, in _request
     return self._session.send(r, **_settings)
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 483, in send
     timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 119, in __init__
     self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, "connect")
   File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/my-jenkins-job/.tox/appdev-ci-staging/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 156, in _validate_timeout
     raise ValueError(
 ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x7efe5adb9aa0>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

As nothing had changed on my side in my configuration, it looks like an upstream issue.

I was using `requests` Python library in my job and `requests` uses `urllib3`.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A new version `2.0.2` of `urllib3` was released on May 4, 2023, which can be seen here: [urllib3 2.0.2 - Release history](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/2.0.2/#history)

As my job installs the Python libraries in the beginning of the job using pip in a virtual Python environment, it started installing the latest version of `urllib3` which had some issues. So, it is looks an upstream issue.

**I fixed it by adding `urllib3>=1.26.15,<2` in my `requirements.txt` file.**

Comment: thanks, putting `python_jenkins==1.8.0 urllib3<2.0.2` fixed it for me